# Не получается принять данные из wc_get_order($order_id);

Tags: php, woocommerce

Нужно собрать данные заказа после его отправки, но выдает ошибку

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_data() on null
```

Я так понимаю, дело в том, что не принимается $order_id созданного заказа. Прошу помочь.

```php
class sendWaybill {

 private $order;

 public function __construct() {
  $this->order = wc_get_order($order_id);
 }

 private function createOrderFields() {
  $order_fields = [];
  $order_data = $this->order->get_data();
  $payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];

  $order_fields += [
   'payment_method' => $payment_method
  ]

  return $order_fields;

 }

 private function createWaybill() {
  $waybill = [];

  $waybill['orders'] = $this->createOrderFields();
 }

 return print_r($waybill);

}

function sendDataAfterSubmit() {
    $request = new sendWaybill();
    return $request->createWaybill();
}

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'sendDataAfterSubmit');
```

Comment: А куда вы его передаёте? И как вы его принимаете? Конструктор его не видит

Comment: @walfter А как мне тогда получить правильно объект заказа внутри класса? Понимаю, вопрос наверное глупый, но я бы был благодарен за наводку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно как то так должно выглядеть я думаю

```
class sendWaybill {

    private $order;
    public $waybill;

    public function __construct($order_id) {
        $this->waybill = [];
        $this->order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    }

    private function createOrderFields() {
        $order_fields = [];
        $order_data = $this->order->get_data();
        $payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];

        $order_fields = [
            'payment_method' => $payment_method
        ];
        return $order_fields;
    }

    private function createWaybill() {
        $this->waybill['orders'][] = $this->createOrderFields();
    }
}

function sendDataAfterSubmit($order_id) {
    $request = new sendWaybill($order_id);
    $request->createWaybill();
    print_r($request->waybill);
}

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'sendDataAfterSubmit', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает! Премного благодарен!